# wp_remote_post rabobank omnikassa (version2) - error 5001

Tags: wp-remote-post

i am actually not sure if this should be a wordpress question/issue or should be asked elsewhere (but one thing might cause the other..)
in any event, trying to write a custom rabobank omnikassa integration , i only ever get a "Invalid or missing signature" result.
according to the (not very helpful) omnikassa support answer this is down to

> - the refresh token is not complete
> - a expired token
> - use of the sandbox token or vice versa

which isn't really helpful at all as

> - a) of course i have used the whole refresh token
> - b) token expired is not the case (refresh toke expires in 2099 - as its a sandbox token)
> - c) of course i am using sandbox token etc for sandbox testing

the code - as it stands - looks like this (of course using variables for the order parameters), so if there's anyone at all that can come up with an idea why this does not work / what i'm doing wrong or has any ideas or hints as to what else i should be trying , i would be more than grateful.

```
        /*
            [url - sandbox]
        */
        $apiUrl = 'https://betalen.rabobank.nl/omnikassa-api-sandbox';

        /*
            Sandbox RefreshToken and Signing key
            (obviuosly the whole token/keys are being used here)
        */
        $RefreshToken = 'abc...xyz';
        $SigningKey = 'ABC...XYZ';


        /*
            get token
        */
        $response = wp_remote_get( $apiUrl.'/gatekeeper/refresh', array(
            'headers'  => array( 
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $RefreshToken ,
            ),
        ));
        $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
        $token_data = json_decode( $body, true);


        /*
        token_data returns something like
            [token] => eyJr.......................EnxK
            [validUntil] => 2018-04-07T18:03:23.692+0000
            [durationInMillis] => 3600000
        */


        /*
            [set orderData]
        */
        $omnikassaOrder=array();
        $omnikassaOrder['timestamp'] = 2018-04-07T17:03:20+00:00;
        $omnikassaOrder['merchantOrderId'] = 101;
        $omnikassaOrder['amount'] = array();
        $omnikassaOrder['amount']['currency'] = 'EUR';
        $omnikassaOrder['amount']['amount'] = 797;
        $omnikassaOrder['language'] = 'NL';
        $omnikassaOrder['description'] = 'Your order at test' ;
        $omnikassaOrder['merchantReturnURL'] = 'http://www.test.com/orders/?id=2666ea175d0a223114db596c86';


        /*
            string to hash 
        */
        $toHash = array();
        $toHash[] = $omnikassaOrder['timestamp'];
        $toHash[] = $omnikassaOrder['merchantOrderId'];
        $toHash[] = $omnikassaOrder['amount']['currency'];
        $toHash[] = $omnikassaOrder['amount']['amount'] ;
        $toHash[] = $omnikassaOrder['language'];
        $toHash[] = $omnikassaOrder['description'];
        $toHash[] = $omnikassaOrder['merchantReturnURL'];

        /*
            add signature
        */
        $omnikassaOrder['signature'] = hash_hmac('sha512', json_encode(implode(',',$toHash)), base64_decode($SigningKey));



        /*
            post to omnikassa 
        */
        $response = wp_remote_post( $apiUrl.'/order/server/api/order', array(
            'headers'  => array( 
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json' ,
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token_data['token'] ,
            ),
            'body' => json_encode($omnikassaOrder),
        ));
        $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
        $redirect_data = json_decode( $body, true );            


        /*
        redirect_data  returns always
        Array
        (
            [errorCode] => 5001
            [consumerMessage] => Invalid or missing signature
        )
        */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out (in case it's helpful to someone else) that

```
$omnikassaOrder['signature'] = hash_hmac('sha512', json_encode(implode(',',$toHash)), base64_decode($SigningKey));
```

should have been simply the following (without json_encode )

```
$omnikassaOrder['signature'] = hash_hmac('sha512', implode(',',$toHash), base64_decode($SigningKey));
```